# Laravel - Get additional column value from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, loops, orm, pivot-table

I have Stores and Medicines tables with many to many relationship. Storing and updating work fine with `attach` and `sync`. The table structure is like below. I want to retrieve value of extra column `(expired)`.

```
store_id | medicine_id | expired
    1         2           1
    1         3           0
```

Also I need to count total medicines which expired like this

[image: Count pivot values]

Both models have `withPivot('expired')` model relation.

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $medicine = Medicine::findOrFail($id);
    $stores = $medicine->findorfail($id)->stores()->get();
    return view ('medicines', compact('medicine', 'stores'));
}
```

**View**

I can list medicines with this

```
@foreach ($stores as $store)
{{ $store->value('name') }}
{!! $store->pivot->expired == 1 ?
'Expired' : 'Not-Expired' !!}
<a href="{{ route('store', $store->id) }}">View</a>
@endforeach
```

I tried to count Cities like this:

```
@foreach($stores as $store)
{{ ($store->pivot->expired==1) }}
@endforeach
```

It gives 1 1. How can I count total cities with have expired Cetamols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

`Sum` on the relationship collection:

```
$stores->sum('pivot.expired');
```

`Sum` on the Query Builder:

```
Medicine::findOrFail($id)->stores()->sum('expired');
```

Also your controller code does not make much sense at the moment and could be simplified to this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $medicine = Medicine::findOrFail($id);
    $stores = $medicine->stores;

    return view('medicines', compact('medicine', 'stores'));
}
```

I removed the second call to `findOrFail()` and removed the `get()` since it is unnecessary.